# Sizes of variables on different platforms

Tags: java, c++

Currently I'm learning C++ and Java. I know that sizes of variables on different platforms are implementation related so some preprocessing is needed to add typedefs in order to have variables of fixed sizes in C++, so I wanted to know how is the constancy of variable sizes achieved in Java.
Thank you.

Comment: They are just different languages with different requirements...

Comment: Java defines the size of it's types. c++ has some requirements but leaves the exact size up to the implementation. It's all about what the language is trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for quick replies but I guess my question wasn't understood correctly. I wanted to know about the implementation and not about the standard definitions

Comment: @Razmik C++ is not Java.  Just because they look similar doesn't mean they are the same thing.

Comment: So you are asking us about the exact sizes of variables? In `Java` they are all the same cross-platform and you can look it up on Google. In `C++` you have to look for specific implementation. There are too many of them to simply specify. Maybe someone can provide a link for all  specifications, if it exists at all?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the "size of a variable"?

Comment: Of course they are( I'm a newbie, sorry if i asked something wrong) but I wanted to know something about the technologies used, if it's a correct term to use.

Comment: The memory it occupies in the RAM

Comment: @Razmik There are more factors than the type determining how much memory is occupied in RAM, like alignment for instance.

Comment: Instead of asking questions on StackOverflow, how about reading about your question first in actual Java language specification? It's pretty clearly defined what a type means and how different types are defined.

Answer (score 2):

In java the sizes of the primitive types are as follows:

1. byte

   - Size: 1 byte
   - Range: −128 to 127
2. short

   - Size: 2 bytes
   - Range: −32768 to 32767
3. int

   - Size: 4 bytes
   - Range: −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
4. long

   - Size: 8 bytes
   - Range: 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to
     9,223,372,036,854,755,807
5. float

   - Size: 4 bytes
   - Range 3.4e−038 to 3.4e+038
6. double

   - Size: 8 bytes
   - 1.7e−308 to 1.7e+038
7. char

   - Size: 2 bytes
   - Range: u0000 (0) to uffff (65,535, inclusive)
8. boolean

   - Size: It's JVM dependent, but Sun's implementation is 1 byte
   - Range: true and false